# Laravel country code and phone number validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

| Country | Coutry code | Digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 2 | 11 |
| KSA | 3 | 9 |
| USA | 1 | 9 |

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
    '*.sender_phone_code' => ['required', 'integer', 'digits:3'],
    '*.sender_phone_number'   => ['required', 'integer', 'digits:9']
]}
```

How to validate the above phone number and country code validation in validation rule Laravel.

Comment: So you want `phone_number` length to be validated based on `country_code`?

Comment: yes mean if user add usa code then number must be 9 digit, if user add India code then number must be 11 digit.

Comment: One way would be to write a custom validator

Answer (score 1):

I use [`giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php`](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) for this:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
    '*.sender_phone_code' => ['required', 'integer', 'digits:3'],
    '*.sender_phone_number'   => ['required', 'integer', 'digits:9', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
            try {
                $phoneNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($value);
            } catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
            if (!$phoneUtil->isValidNumber($phoneNumberProto)) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        }]
]}
```